# TypeError: User.save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to post the user data to mongodb but I am getting an error as :

> TypeError: user.save is not a function

how to fix this?

I am using express

here is my code:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  let params = {
    id: req.body.id,
    name: req.body.name
  }
  User
    .save({ params })
    .find()
    .then((data) => {
      res.render('index', { title: 'List', data: data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.send(err);
    });
})
```

This is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String
});

User.pre('save', function (next) {
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Comment: `.save()` is an "instance method". You want [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new `User` instance and call `save` on it

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  let user = new User ({
    id: req.body.id,
    name: req.body.name
  })

  user.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(err);
                }

                User
                 .find()
                 .then((data) => {
                     res.render('index', { title: 'List', data: data });
                 })
                 .catch((err) => {
                     return res.send(err);
                 });
  });
})
```

Comment: Could you tell me why I need to create a new instance, please.

Comment: Because the `save` method is an instance method. You call it on the instance you want to save, not the `User` type in general.